# Can not post to server using node express

Tags: node.js, express, post

I am trying to post data from postman to my node server, I keep getting 404.

Is my code setup correctly to receive post to `http://localhost:8080/back-end/test` and if not how can I fix it ?

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var nodePardot = require('node-pardot');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var rp = require('request-promise');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Start the server
app.listen(port);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // support encoded bodies
console.log('Test server started! At http://localhost:' + port); // Confirms server start

var firstFunction = function () {
    return new Promise (function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            app.post('back-end/test.js', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                res.send(login);
                resolve({
                    data_login_email: login
                });
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
};
```

I am posting LoginEmail and keep getting 404.

Comment: did you call `firstFunction` anywhere in your file?

Comment: Why do you use the `app.post(...)` within time out?

Comment: what is the purpose of returning a promise here.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki yes the function is being called at the bottom of the page

Comment: @HatzavWolff I have three functions with different time outs and a set list of promises

Comment: purpose of using promise here?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I return promise as a call back to pass data to a different function

Comment: why not use middleware chains?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki +1 for the info. I have not used middleware chains ill take a look thanks

Comment: Looks good ! ill have to refactor the code for this [Middelware-chain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/middleware-chain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move `app.post()` outside of the timeout, promise, and `firstFunction`.
2. There is no proceeding paths defined in your code, so the path must start with a `/`: `/back-end/test.js`. Don't forget the extension since you've defined it.

Comment: Ahh man! it was the `/back-end/test` cant believe i did not see that. so part 2 of your answer fixed the problem. as for part 1 I need the code in promise as it passes data between functions and the time out is part of that. But thanks for spotting the `/`